# What type do you use to allow null or data in a React.SetStateAction?

Tags: typescript

I need to add a 'null' at the end of array, as that is what is expected by a 3rd part library to signal that there is more data to fetch. Without 'StrictNullCheck' enabled everything is working fine. What should my type be here?

data is

```
const data: {
    _id: string;
    name: string;
}[]
```

Code:

```
const [companies, setCompanies] = React.useState<ItemListData[] | null>([])
setCompanies([...data, null] // Adding a null here is causing the type error
```

Error:

```
Argument of type '({ _id: string; name: string; } | null)[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<ItemListData[] | null>'.
  Type '({ _id: string; name: string; } | null)[]' is not assignable to type 'ItemListData[]'.
    Type '{ _id: string; name: string; } | null' is not assignable to type 'ItemListData'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'ItemListData'.ts(2345)
```

Comment: I think what the interpretter is thinking is that it is either a list of objects or the whole thing is null. You may want to adjust the bracing (`<>`) such that the `[]` is outside the scope of the object or `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that this:

```
React.useState<ItemListData[] | null>
```

means "the type can be an array of `ItemListData` or the type can be `null`".  Which means you either have an array or you have `null`, but the array itself must contain `ItemListData`.

What you want is "the type can be an array of either `ItemListData` or `null`".  Which would mean that the type itself must always be an array, but that array can *contain* either `ItemListData` or `null`.

Perhaps something like this:

```
React.useState<(ItemListData | null)[]>
```